# Tooltip for CSS :before

Tags: css, html

I've created a CSS based text prefix, like this:

```
.staff-only:before {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f023";  /* padlock */
}
```

It shows a padlock in front of a text, indicating that this text is secret. I would like to show a hint (aka tooltip, or HTML5 title), reading "Visible only to staff members", that would show up when the users hovers over the padlock. How could I achieve it?

**Full example**
So far with the help of comments, I've got (stuck) here:

```css
.staff-only {
    background-color: #c1ebf3;
    color: #808080;
    padding-left: -2px;
    padding-right: 0.2em;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.staff-only:before {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f023";  /* padlock */
    color: silver;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.staff-only:after {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f13e";  /* open padlock */
    color: silver;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.staff-only:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}   
.staff-only .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    color: darkred;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    width: 0;

    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>
  <span class="staff-only">
      Secret text
      <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span> 
  </span>
</p>
```

This is what I get. The screenshot shows two comments, one public and one staff-only. The problem is the empty space to the right from the staff-only comment, which seems to fit the tooltip text. Cannot cope with it :(

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can use :after to show the tip. Make the element relative and display block or inline block. The after will be displayed when the element is hovered with position absolutew above it. Is this what you want?

Comment: Hopefully the text will be dynamically loaded with ajax or something, not in the html where anyone can just view source code and see what the secret text is.

Comment: @Gary, sure thing, the text is put there by Django, it won't be there in case the person does not have the right permission.

Comment: @Maxwells.c, actually, :after is already in use. I omitted it for the sake of brevity (didn't expect the solutions will go along those lines). I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: if it is in use, just add an new spam element and use it instead of before/after

Comment: @Maxwells.c, trying exactly that, so far without much success. I'll post another update if I fail and don't get an answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for help. Eventually I found a really elegant solution: use the `title` attribute:

From [HTML 5.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/dom.html#the-title-attribute) standard:

> The title attribute represents advisory information for the element, such as would be appropriate for a tooltip. ...[On] a paragraph, it could be a footnote or commentary on the text;

```css
.staff-only {
    background-color: #c1ebf3;
    color: #808080;
    padding-left: -2px;
    padding-right: 0.2em;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.staff-only:before {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f023";  /* padlock */
    color: silver;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.staff-only:after {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f13e";  /* open padlock */
    color: silver;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<span title="This text is only visible to admins" class="staff-only">Secret text</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

After you update your question you should wrap the element with a `<span>`:

```css
.staff-only {
  background-color: #c1ebf3;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #808080;
  padding-left: -2px;
  padding-right: 0.2em;
}
.staff-only:before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f023";  /* padlock */
  color: silver;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
.tooltip:hover:after {
  content: "Visible only to staff members!";
  color: silver;
  font-size:0.9em;
  padding:0 10px;
  background:black;
}
.tooltip-data:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-msg);
  color: silver;
  font-size:0.9em;
  padding:0 10px;
  background:black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>
  <span class="tooltip">
    <span class="staff-only">Secret text</span>
  </span>
</p>
<p>
  <span class="tooltip-data" data-msg="Visible only to staff members!">
    <span class="staff-only">Secret text</span>
  </span>
</p>
```

---

**Original Answer:**

You can use `:after` to display a little tooltip:

```css
.staff-only {
  background-color: #c1ebf3;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #808080;
  padding-left: -2px;
  padding-right: 0.2em;
}
.staff-only:before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f023";  /* padlock */
  color: silver;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
.staff-only:hover:after {
  content: "Visible only to staff members!";
  color: silver;
  font-size:0.9em;
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>
  <span class="staff-only">Secret text</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Yeah... that padding was bothering me too! :D

Comment: Yes, looks much better :D

Comment: @GaryHayes, I have padding in separate lines on purpose, because I can never remember which is which otherwise :)

Comment: Unfortunately, :after is already in use. I omitted it for the sake of brevity (didn't expect the solutions will go along those lines). I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at how W3Schools handles tooltips:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

```css
/* Tooltip container */
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black; /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
}

/* Tooltip text */
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px; /* Use half of the width (120/2 = 60), to center the tooltip */
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
 
    /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    
    /* Fade in */
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;  /* At the top of the tooltip */
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    
    /* Fade in */
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, trying that, failing so far. Please see the updated question. I believe their secret is the use of "div" which spans the full line anyway.

Comment: No, their secret lies in making setting the container (`.staff-only` in your case) to have `position: relative` and then the tooltip to `position: absolute` and also set a `width` for their tooltip.